# runtime exception: "No provider for ReportService"

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm revisiting a setup I started for an ng2 app in a VS2015 web project. It was working at one point.  The app uses Typescript and builds as expected.  For example, it builds without errors but fails if I put random characters in the ts so the ts appears to be building as expected.

I do have a ReportService in the app but I commented out all refs and I still receive the runtime error in the post title.  First I'd like to simply comment out the ReportService reference, get the page to load without error and then reintroduce ReportService after that.  Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Here's a zip file https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qv3cq711nclrzp/basic-angular-2.zip?dl=0.  Will you please take a look and lmk what the issue might be?

Comment: Unlikely anybody will download random zip files from the internet. It's also very unlikely someone will debug a full project for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new to ng2 and the solution is also using Typescript so I wanted to provide a full solution because I don't know if there's something random that I might be missing.  You just need to build the solution and then view index.html in browser and look at the web console output.

Answer (score 0):

`No provider for xxx` often appears when your service is not provided by `module` in which you have your component, or by `module` imported by given `module`.

Example:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyService } from "./my.service";
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Now you can use `MyService` in `MyComponent`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MyService } from "./my.component";

@Component()
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private service: MyService) {}

    public someMethod(): void {
        this.service.someMethod();
    }
}
```

You can also export that service from `module` to use it in another modules:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyService } from "./my.service";
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ],
  providers: [ MyService ],
  exports: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Now you can use `MyService` wherever you import `MyModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MyModule } from "./my.module";
import { AnotherComponent } from './another.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ MyModule ]
  declarations: [ AnotherComponent ],
})
export class MyModule {}


import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MyService } from "./my.component";

@Component()
export class AnotherComponent {
    constructor(private service: MyService) {}

    public anotherMethod(): void {
        this.service.someMethod();
    }
}
```